# startup Rcmd with .Rprofile

Tags: r, user-interface

When I introduce people to `R` I often find that `Rcmdr` is one of the easiest ways to get people to learn, since it assumes very little specific R knowledge, but does build it by showing the commands used.

In order to lower the threshold I want to be able to setup a computer so that `Rcmdr` can be loaded  in an intuitive way (i.e. open a file / shortcut). However, I also want people to be able to start `R` without this (ruling out the use of `.Rprofile`).

I have tried using

```
R -f Rcmdr.R
```

with `Rcmdr.R` being

```
library(Rcmdr)
```

but this gives an Rcmdr error about needing to be loaded in an interactive session. I have tried forcing this with the `--interactive` flag, but this does not seem to make a difference.

Is there any other way to create a file which can startup R with Rcmdr?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass the environment variable `R_DEFAULT_PACKAGES` and start R as below:

```
R_DEFAULT_PACKAGES=Rcmdr R
```